# How to obfuscate names of the resource files located in a Java JAR archive?

Tags: java, embedded-resource

I've created the JAVA desktop application which uses a large number of files located in a resource folder inside the JAR file. I would like to prevent the user of my app from uncovering the names of these files (someone could achieve that simply by extracting the JAR archive).

Is there any way to obfuscate or rename in bulk these filenames both in the JAVA code and in the resource folder? I tried to find this kind of solution in ProGuard, but I couldn't.

Of course, I could manually change the names of the files and the code lines to replace the original ones, but there are over thousand of them and it would take ages. I would also prefer rather to obfuscate than rename the filenames, because keeping the original filenames in my code would make my work easier. Do you have any ideas what could I do?

Thank you for your support.

Bartek

Comment: Md5 hash the file names in your source and on disk.